# store nearby url and insert into tooltip with jQuery

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I have some jQuery that makes these images expand on hover and a tooltip with the image title appears.

http://jsfiddle.net/nathanbweb/7juZY/5/

(It's two separate plugins; yes, I'm sure there's a more efficient ideal way. But that's not my question.) Is there an easy way to insert a "More Info" link into this tooltip that matches the "More Info" link already under the thumbnail?

I think it will end up looking something like this:

```
$(".tooltip").append(' '<a href="' + thelink + '">More Info</a>' ');
```

but I'm so bad with variables I need help storing the link from one location (at ul>li>a ) and then re-using it in the append.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, something like this would do.

```
var thelink;
thelink = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
$(".tooltip").append('<a href="' + thelink + '">More Info</a>');
```

I don't think there's need to use the tooltip plugin, you got it almost right in your code (the commented part) just do a little research on variables in javascript and how to use them.

edit: i down't know what happens when the tooltip gets created after the hover fired, i guess it won't work then, i would suggest to use something like the code below on hover to create the tooltip.

```
var title, tooltip, thelink, moreinfo;

thelink = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
moreinfo = $('<a href="' + thelink + '">More Info</a>');
title = $(this).find("img").attr("title");
tooltip = $("<div class='tooltip'>" + title + "</div>");

tooltip.append(moreinfo);
$(this).append(tooltip);
```

Comment: that's the code I need for the link, but when I try it in Firebug, the More Info link is "/undefined" and in production it's just a blank '/'  any ideas?

Comment: here it is in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nathanbweb/7juZY/18/  (Now I'm wrapping each image with the link.) But it takes the first link in the ul and assigns it to every element. I need the img to take the link that's in the same li .

Comment: does there need to be an each or this somewhere?

Comment: the way you are using this you should put it inside a $.("li").each(function() { //function here } ); selecting the href attribute of all elements makes no sense

Comment: ok, can someone straighten out my mangled syntax: http://jsfiddle.net/nathanbweb/7juZY/25/ (top of the JS window)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an `<a></a>` tag inside a title attribute. I would recommend having jQuery grab the title and display it in a Div then position the Div over the box you are hovering over.